# Pyschool Topic 11: Q 13

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working my way through pyschool to learn python and I have ran into an issue solving the following question.

> Write a function `printTwos(n)` that takes in a number as argument and
>   returns a string composed of an odd number multiplied by 2s such that
>   the final value is equal to `n`. There should be equal number of 2s on
>   both sides. Extra 2 should appear at the front of the string. Note:
>   The value of the odd number can be 1.

Examples

```
>>> printTwos(1)
'1'
>>> printTwos(2)
'2 * 1'
>>> printTwos(10)
'2 * 5'
>>> printTwos(20)
'2 * 5 * 2'
>>> printTwos(30)
'2 * 15'
>>> printTwos(32)
'2 * 2 * 2 * 1 * 2 * 2'
>>> printTwos(80)
'2 * 2 * 5 * 2 * 2'
```

I believe I have it working.

```
def printTwos(n):
count = 0
if n == 1:
    return '1'

if n == 2:
    return '2 * 1'
while n%2 == 0:
   n = n/2
   count +=1

if count%2 == 0:
    twos = count/2
    myoutput = ('2 * ' * twos, str(n), ' * 2' * twos)
    return ''.join(myoutput)
else:
    twos = count/2
    twofront = twos+1

    myoutput = ('2 * ' * twofront, str(n), ' * 2' * twos)
    return ''.join(myoutput)
```

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Fine. You can improve your function with handling for odd and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def printTwos(n): 
    if(n%2==1):return str(n)
    else:
        if(n%4==0):return str('2 * ')+ printTwos(n/4) +str(' * 2')
        else: return str('2 * ')+ printTwos(n/2)
```